# Sql -after group by I need to take rows with newest date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to write a query in sql and I can't do it correctly. I have a table with 7 columns 1st_num, 2nd_num, 3rd_num, opening_Date, Amount, code, cancel_Flag.

For every 1st_num, 2nd_num, 3rd_num I want to take only the record with the min (cancel_flag), and if there's more then 1 row so take the the newest opening Date.

But when I do group by and choose min and max for the relevant fields, I get a mix of the rows, for example:

```
1. 12,130,45678,2015-01-01,2005,333,0
2. 12,130,45678,2015-01-09,105,313,0
```

The result will be

```
:12,130,45678,2015-01-09,2005,333,0
```

and that mixes the rows into one
Microsoft sql server 2008 . using ssis by visual studio 2008
my code is :

```
SELECT 
    1st_num, 
    2nd_num,
    3rd_num,
    MAX(opening_date),
    MAX (Amount),
    code,
    MIN(cancel_flag) 
FROM do. tablename 
GROUP BY 
    1st_num, 
    2nd_num,
    3rd_num,
    code
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

How do I take the row with the max date or.min cancel flag  as it is without mixing values?

I can't really post my code because of security reasons but I'm sure you can help.

thank you,
Oren

Comment: Which DBMS are you referring to? And if you can't post your exact code, can you post some "anonymous" code to reproduce the problem?

Comment: I just edited my question. Microsoft SQL Server 2008 on Windows.

Comment: Then you should follow sagis answer and make use of the [ROW_NUMBER() function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734(v=sql.120).aspx)

Comment: I just tried sagi's answer . has some syntax misunderstanding with his answer . trying to work on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very difficult like this to answer, because every DBMS has different syntax.

Anyways, for most dbms this should work. Using row_number() function to rank the rows, and take only the first one by our definition (all your conditions):

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT t.*,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY t.1st_num,t.2nd_num,t.3rd_num order by t.cancel_flag asc,t.opening_date desc) as row_num
    FROM YourTable t ) as tableTempName
WHERE row_num = 1
```

Comment: sounds complicated . can you please explain why do you use the temp field row num ? will the code run in a loop ?

Comment: No, no loop. This is not complicated at all, row_number is an analytic function on most of dbms's, which will rank you rows acording to their flag and opening date, and will just take the biggest one(meaning - the smallest flag with the biggest date) @user3680496

Comment: I tried what you suggested.  it's missing something . the function ROW_NUMBER ()  is ok but the where statement is misplaced I guess

Comment: worked like charm after few syntax corrections.  thank you

Comment: I'm still having some issues . I need  the function to group by the first 3 numbers . so at the end for every 1st_num,2nd_num, 3rd_num  I will get only 1 row .

Answer (score 0):

Use `NOT EXISTS` to return a row as long as no other row with same 1st_num, 2nd_num, 3rd_num has a lower cancel_flag value, or same cancel_flag but a higher opening_Date.

```
select *
from tablename t1
where not exists (select 1 from tablename t2
                  where t2.1st_num = t1.1st_num
                    and t2.2nd_num = t1.2nd_num
                    and t2.3rd_num = t1.3rd_num
                    and (t2.cancel_flag < t1.cancel_flag
                         or (t2.cancel_flag = t1.cancel_flag and
                             t2.opening_Date > t1.opening_Date)))
```

Core ANSI SQL-99, expected to work with (almost) any dbms.

Comment: and if exist how do I do the swap Orson it's happening automatically?